# Ajuda com Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Antes de perguntar procurei várias referências, porém ainda não entendo muito e consegui chegar somente até certo ponto.

O meu objetivo é validar que uma `string` específica possua 10 caracteres, sendo os dois primeiros letras maiúsculas, e os outros 8 caracteres números.

As duas primeiras letras devem ser **obrigatóriamente** AD, AG ou EX. Não podem ser AE ou EG por exemplo.

Para tanto tenho a seguinte `Regex` `/^[A(D|G)|EX]{2}[0-9]{8}$/gm`. Porém ela não cumpre a segunda regra. Ela permite que a letras AGDEX estejam mixadas, e não na ordem específica desejada.

Estou utilizando o [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) para validar a minha `regex` com os seguintes valores:

**EX09551115** 
**AD09551115** 
**AG09551115**

EA09551115 
EG09551115 
AE09551115 
AX09551115 
DG09551115 
GD09551115 
XE09551115 
GA09551115 
DA09551115 
XD09551115 
XG09551115 
GX09551115 
DX09551115

Apenas os valores em negrito devem ser valores válidos.

O que eu desejo é saber como eu faço para satisfazer a segunda condição. Não precisa deixar uma `regex` pronta, apenas me mostrar o caminho já será de grande ajuda.

Referências também serão bem vindas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acredito que essa regex `^(AD|AG|EX)[0-9]{8}$` ou `^(AD|AG|EX)\d{8}$` resolve o problema.

No início da linha é esperado (uma opção do grupo) `AD` ou `AG` ou `EX` seguido de números que devem se repetir exatamente 8 vezes.

Em um lista os metacaracteres perdem suas funções `[A(D|G)|EX]{2}` logo o grupo e o `OU`(pipe) e você espera que isso ocorra exatamente duas vezes.

Comment: Eu tinha tentado isso, porém por uma falta de atenção não removi o `{2}` que era o que acabava com a condição. Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @RichardDias, o problema não era só o `{2}` mas os itens da lista, pegue a regex orginal da sua pergunta e veja se nas entradas `||09551115`, `((09551115` ou `))09551115` batem com o padrão especificado na regex ;)

Comment: Sim, elas batem, que loco. Mas o que eu quis dizer, é que eu tinha tentado essa ideia dos grupos `(AD|AG|EX)`, porém não tinha removido o `{2}`

Comment: Algum ponto da resposta está errado ou pode ser melhorado?

Comment: Se tiver alguma referência legal para quem tá iniciando compreender melhor, seria legal, mas no geral sanou o meu problema.

Comment: @RichardDias, posso adicionar depois mais alguma coisa, nas tags geralmente tem um wiki com informações e alguns materiais, click no nome da tag, depois na aba info. Da regex  o endereço é http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info Qualquer coisa chama aí

Answer (score 2):

Opa amigo, tente essa regex: https://regex101.com/r/tX6fT8/1

A sua regex `/^[A(D|G)|EX]{2}[0-9]{8}$/gm` não funcionou porque você não agrupou as letras AD, AG e EX deixando o A livre juntamente com o D, G e o EX dentro do grupo.

Uma segunda opção seria esta https://regex101.com/r/tX6fT8/2, você também pode usar o `$` e o `^` para definir linhas se preferir.

Answer (score 1):

Isso funciona:

```
/^(AG|AD|EX)(\d{8})$/gm
```

Aqui é onde os **grupos** em expressão regular fazem sentido:
Primeiro grupo é uma combinação de letras maiúsculas como **AG** ou **AD** ou **EX**;
Segundo grupo é uma sequência de dígitos tendo o tamanho 8.